# R a faster weekday method

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

Hi I am trying to convert the given dates into their respective weekdays, I have a data set of million lines, and I am only using the column with the dates in it.

I am currently using

```
ifelse(wday(data$started_at)==1,7,wday(data$started_at)-1)
```

I want Monday to be indicated as 1 and Sunday as 7, however, I do not really care, I would much rather have a faster program.

As trial data you use :

```
   x<- rep("2022-02-01 00:00:04",1000000)
```

This is what I currently have

```
   ifelse(wday(x)==1,7,wday(x)-1)
```

I am trying to make it much faster, it currently takes 17second on my computer.

Comment: Consider updating your trial data so that your conditions may be triggered.

Comment: Perhaps try to work with `POSIXct` dates instead of characters

Answer (score 2):

There is an argument in `lubridate::wday` called `week_start`:

```
x<- "2022-02-01 00:00:04"
wday(x, week_start = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The extra `ifelse` and calling `wday` twice is not needed here. Curiously, the following is slightly faster, and gives an integer instead of the default numeric from `wday`.

```
x <- sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2000/01/01'), by="day"), 1e7, replace = T)

z <- c(7L, 1:6)

bench::mark(
  x = wday(x, week_start = 1),
  y = z[wday(x)]
)[c(3,5,7,9)]
    median mem_alloc n_itr total_time
  <bch:tm> <bch:byt> <int>   <bch:tm>
1       1s     534MB     1         1s
2    879ms     534MB     1      879ms
```